# Joomla 2.5 Strict Standards

Tags: php, joomla

I have this website i am building with Joomla! 2.5. It is a shopping cart and i was building it on my Xampp bu the minute i uploaded it to my server, it doesn't show anything on the front page. The admin section is okay but the front page doesn't show anything. When i turn on error reporting for development, i get the below error.

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/sites/mydomain/public_html/beta/plugins/system/jblibrary/jblibrary.php on line 26

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/sites/mydomain/public_html/beta/plugins/system/jblibrary/jblibrary.php on line 55

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/sites/mydomain/public_html/beta/plugins/system/jatypo/jatypo.php on line 55

Fatal error: t3import not found object: core.libs.browser in /home/sites/mydomain/public_html/beta/plugins/system/jat3/jat3/core/common.php on line 33
```

I took a look at one of the files throwing the error and the line below seemed like the problem.

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
```

I have tried to modify it to;

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
```

But the error is still thrown. I have also tried switching the PHP versions but the error persists. I just can't seem to figure out why the site is working on my localhost and not on my server. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Turn off strict errors.

Comment: I have also tried using php.ini to turn off the errors.
`error_reporting = E_All & -E_Notice
display_errors = off`

Still doesn't work

Comment: So, your question is: how to turnoff error displaying. Search for it.

Comment: My question is not how to turn off errors, that is a piece of cake mate @sectus.
My question is, why is the front page not showing anything while the back end is okay. Normally even if you have errors, it draws the HTML and shows the errors. Mine is not showing the HTML code that builds the site. That is my question mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your errors tells you why Joomla is white-screening. The `Strict standards` warnings are just warnings, they don't stop execution.

`Fatal error: t3import not found object: core.libs.browser in /home/sites/mydomain/public_html/beta/plugins/system/jat3/jat3/core/common.php on line 33`

A `Fatal error` is just that, it can't be recovered from.

In this case, your website is crashing because the front-end Joomla is trying to load a T3 based template that in turn tries to load the T3 framework which needs `/jat3/jat3/core/common.php` and it can't find it on the live server.

If it's working on your Xampp setup then it probably means you didn't move it correctly/move all the files or set the paths up correctly in the `configuration.php`.

The easiest and safest way to move a site from development to live is to use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) in conjunction with [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/downloads/akeeba-kickstart.html) which will package your development site into a single file and include an installer in it. Then you can upload the backup file and the `kickstart` file to your server and follow the [kickstart documentation](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-kickstart-documentation.html) to "restore" your development version to the live server.

Comment: What Craig says. Plus installing the latest version of JAT3 framework will probably fix this.

Comment: Thanks guys, let me try this and i will let you know if it works. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hey guys i just want to say thanks a bunch. Spent a whole lot of time trying to fix this but finally i managed. I used the Akeeba tools and kicstart but it still showed the errors. I had the latest JAT3 framework installed but i just tried to re-install it and voila! I appreciate your efforts, my site is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i had just encountered this error when i deployed my joomla instance from windows to a linux server. t3import is looking for /core/libs/browser.php but the actual filename is Browser.php. Linux is case-sensitive so it didn't find the correct file. i just renamed Browser.php to browser.php and it worked fine.